# open and read PT. file using python code by pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to read a PT file with python and I don't know how, I want to open it with python
can you help me please, any ideas?

Comment: How was the file created. Where did you get it?

Answer (score 4):

If your `.PT` file is related to the weight and bias of a `model`.

You must first install pytorch in your pc.

for more information  install go to [this](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

then use this  :

```
model = torch.load(PATH)
```

[saving_loading_models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)

You could iterate the parameters to get all weight and bias params via:(see weitht and bias)

```
for param in model.parameters():
   ....
# or
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch

# Load the file
pt_file = torch.load("./myfile.pt")

# Print the head of the file
print(pt_file[:5])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: As Tyler2P mentioned, [a code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.